# Need help to convert log file into json format

Tags: python

I am new to Python programming. I need help on how to convert below log file into a JSON file.

My log file:

```
DNSCacheInfo

enabled             yes
CacheEntries        0/1024
HitRatio            0/0 (  0.00%)


Async DNS disabled


Performance Counters

Total number of requests                  55
Average Request processing time       0.0006
Total Request processing time         0.0310


default-bucket (Default bucket)

Counter Name               Average         Total      Percent
-------------------------------------------------------------
Number of Requests                            55    (100.00%)
Number of Invocations                        444    (100.00%)
Latency                     0.0001        0.0050    ( 16.13%)
Function Processing Time    0.0005        0.0260    ( 83.87%)
Total Response Time         0.0006        0.0310    (100.00%)
```

I need output like:

```
{ DNSCacheInfo : { enabled : yes , CacheEntries : 0/1024 , HitRatio : 0/0 (  0.00%) }, Async DNS : disabled ,  Performance Counters : {  Total number of requests : 55 ,  Average Request processing time : 0.0006 ,  Total Request processing time : 0.0310 } , default-bucket : { [ Counter Name : Number of Requests , Average : "" , Total : 55 , Percent : (100.00%)],[ Counter Name : Number of Invocations , Average : "" , Total :  444 , Percent : (100.00%)] , ..}}
```

Tried with below code:

```py
datacomplete = {}
with open("test.log") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    
    for line in lines:
            if 'Async DNS' in line:
                val1 = line.split('Async DNS')[1].split(':')[1].strip()
                print(val1)
                datacomplete["Async DNS"]=val1
            if 'DNSCacheInfo' in line:
                DNSCacheInfo={}
                DNSCacheInfo_headings=['enabled','CacheEntries','HitRatio']
```

Can you help me figure out how to complete this?

Comment: I'd recommend looking into **regex** (available in Python as the builtin `re` library) to parse the log file into named groups, then simply populate the `dict`/JSON with the captured values.

Comment: This is totally doable with Python (or any other language for that matter), but I'd first check with whatever generates that log if there are other output options, or maybe an export, because this looks like it's been made to be more human-readable than machine-readable

Comment: Your sample output is not valid JSON.

Comment: Modified the sample output. can anyone help me with the last row and column how can we convert into JSON

Comment: Can someone please answer my above question